# I can't run the angular app , I get this error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\angular-11-spring-boot-jwt-authentication\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-09T10_56_11_734Z-debug.log

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEKoC.png)

Comment: do you have this file? `C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\angular-11-spring-boot-jwt-authentication\package.json`

Comment: What is your node version?

Answer (score 1):

- Delete **node_modules** folder and re-install all your dependencies using **npm install**
- Ensure that you have a stable version of Node
- Run npm start/ng serve from the angular folder